# C# - Exclude Already Followed Users in Second Level Followers

Tags: c#, linq, twitter, where-clause

I want to find followers of my followers that I'm not following in Twitter.

To do this, I have a table called Following which has three coulmns ID, Follower_iD and Following_iD

And my code is the following:

```
var userIDs = database.Followings.Where(u => u.Follower_id == MY.Id);

foreach (var userID in userIDs)
{
     var secondUserIDs = database.Followings.Where(u => u.Follower_id == userID.Following_id).Except(userIDs);
```

Even though I wrote .Except(userIDs) in order to eliminate the people I follow, the output includes the records that I already follow.

To explain my problem better, here is the example:

Assume that my id is 10.

And in the database there are records:

```
follower_id      following_id
    10                11
    10                12
    10                13
    10                14
    14                12
    14                13
    14                15
```

So the problem is, since I'm following both 12 and 13, there is no need to return (14,12) and (14, 13) pairs in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Except` uses set to determine elements which shouldn't be returned, so you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to make it work. But I still don't think it's gonna work with linq to twitter.

However, I would go with following:

```
var userIDs = database.Followings.Where(u => u.Follower_id == MY.Id)
                                 .Select(u => u.Following_id)
                                 .ToList(); // ToList(), to make it happen only once

foreach (var userID in userIDs)
{
     var secondUserIDs = database.Followings.Where(u => u.Follower_id == userID)
                                            .Select(u => u.Following_id)
                                            .Except(userIDs).;
}
```

The difference is, you're taking only IDs, not whole objects in your queries.

**Update**

You can try using `Contains()` to get all without `foreach` loop:

```
var secondUserIDs = database.Followings.Where(u => userIDs.Contains(u.Follower_id) && !userIDs.Contains(u.Following_id))
                                       .Select(u => u.Following_id);
```

Comment: Can you please look at the edited question now, I explained better now, because I didn't understand how except function in your answer eliminate the unnecessary records

Comment: And for the short code I got this error:
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.